# Can't choose the specific ID to Edit the data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

hal1 / view.php

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";
include "cek.php";

$result = $koneksi->query("select * from pengunjung");
$baris = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo "Halaman Admin<br>";
echo "Nama Anda adalah : ".$_SESSION['namauser']. "<br><br>";
echo "<li><a href = edit.php?userid=$baris[id]>[Edit Data Diri]</a></li><br>    
      <li><a href=logout.php> Logout</a></li>";
?>
```

edit.php

```
<?php
include("koneksi.php");
include("cek.php");

$id=$_GET['userid'];

$query = "select * from pengunjung where id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($koneksi,$query);

while ($baris = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<form method=post action=update.php>";
    echo "Nama : <input type=text name=nama value=$baris[1]>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Email : <input type=text name=email value=$baris[2]>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Situs : <input type=text name=situs value=$baris[3]>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type=submit name=submit value=update>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name=id value=$baris[0]>";
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

update.php

```
<?php
include("koneksi.php");

$id=$_POST['id'];
$nama=$_POST['nama'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$situs=$_POST['situs'];

$query = "update pengunjung set id='$id', nama='$nama', email='$email', 
situs='$situs' where id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($koneksi,$query);

echo '<script language="JavaScript">alert("Data telah di update");
    document.location="edit.php"</script>';
?>
```

I used login form and I logged in as a user with specific ID. And I try to edit the data (nama,email,situs) of the user who logged in. 
The problem is why It didn't select the right data (nama,email,situs) of the User who logged in?. Whenever I logged in as different users, and I click the Edit, It always show the data (nama,email,situs) from the first ID/user on the database. Helpp!!

Answer (score 1):

use id variable

```
<?php
include("koneksi.php");
include("cek.php");

$id=$_GET['userid'];

$query = "select * from pengunjung where id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($koneksi,$query);

while ($baris = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   ?>
    <form method=post action=update.php>
   Nama : <input type=text name="nama" value="<?php echo $baris['column1']?>">

    Email : <input type=text name="email" value="<?php echo $baris['column2']?>">

    Situs : <input type=text name=situs value="<?php echo $baris['column3']?>">
    <input type=hidden name=id value="<?php echo $id?>"d>
    <input type=submit name=submit value=update>


    </form>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you Get user id so you can use that in the input field

Comment: bro it working this update page output   Array ( [nama] => [email] => [situs] => [id] => 1 [submit] => update )

Comment: The edit and update is working, but the data given isn't belong to the user who logged in. It always give the data (nama,email,situs) from the first ID in the database, not giving the data of the user who logged in.

Comment: Also can't..
I think the problem is on the hal1/view.php, because when I inspect it on the browser, it shows me like this  <a href="edit.php?userid=15">.
The userid=15 is incorrect, because I logged in as a User with ID = 16. Any idea??

Comment: your view page query have now where condition,

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: in your view page, you write a select query it gives you first record from your table if you last record write "select * from pengunjung  order by id desc"

Answer (score 0):

hal1/view.php

```
<?php
include"koneksi.php";
include "cek.php";

echo "Halaman Admin<br>";
echo "Nama Anda adalah : ".$_SESSION['namauser']. "<br><br>";
echo "  <li><a href = edit.php?userid=$_SESSION[id]>[Edit Data Diri]</a></li><br>   
        <li><a href=logout.php> Logout</a></li>";
 ?>
```

Okay.. So I think I solved the problem by using session, in this case $_SESSION[id] of the user who logged in. I put the session code on the check_user_login.php file, and so I don't need to do the query again in hal1/view.php.

check_user_login.php

```
<?php
include("koneksi.php");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "select * from pengunjung where username='$username' and password='$password'";
$data = mysqli_query($koneksi,$query) or die ("Couldn't execute query");
$hasil = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);

if ($username=="" || $password=="")
{
    echo '<script language="JavaScript">alert("Username atau Password Kosong");
    document.location="index.php"</script>';
}
else
    if($username==$hasil['username'] and $password==$hasil['password'])
    {   
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $hasil['id'];
        $_SESSION['namauser'] = $username;
        header("location:hal1/view.php");
else
{
    echo '<script language="JavaScript">alert("Username atau Password Salah");
    document.location="index.php"</script>';
}
```